# In my situation I want to push input value and store it in array in local storage VUEX. I've tried this but it's not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In my situation I want to push input value and store it in array in local storage VUEX. I create an array in state. First I push my value and then I stringify to set that value to the store in local storage. I get it in my array by parsing my JSON but it is not working. I don't know to where my value goes. Also console gives an error 'push is not a function'.

```
    state:{
    formItems:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formItems'))||[]
},
mutations:{
    formFunction(state, myInput){
        state.formItems.push({myInput});
        localStorage.setItem('formItems', JSON.stringify(state.formItems))
    },


<template>
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <input type="text" v-model="Input">
                <br>
                <button class="btn waves-effect" @click="saveInput">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>{{text}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name:"test",
    data:function(){
        return{
            Input:"",
        }
    },
    methods:{
        saveInput(){
            this.$store.commit('formFunction', this.Input);
            this.Input="";
        }
    },
computed:{
    text(){
        return this.$store.state.formItems;
    },
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just found out that all local storage in browser should be cleared. After clearing it works fine without any problems.